# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable Python 3 Ubuntu

Tags: python, typeerror

Essentially I have run into a problem regarding a Type Error on line 3, I am presented with "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" Any advice would be appreciated /Ubuntu/python3/terminal

```
import os
#Imports operating system modules
user_file_search = input()('Type Millienium2000')
#Prompt the user to enter password
encoded = user_file_search.encode('hex')
#Decodes files based on hex

for root, dirs, files in os.walk ('/Desktop/POP/PoP_Coursework_Assignment/Svr1/documents$'):
    for data in files :
        pass_file = open(os.path.join(root,data)).read()

if(encoded in pass_file):
    print ('This could be the pass : {}'.format(os.path.join(root,data)))
    print ('Located data: {}'.format(pass_file))
#Prints Data retrived
```

I am presented with the following

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "oswalk.py", line 3, in
>
> user_file_search = input()('Type Millienium2000')
>
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE! Code is working fantastically now! Thanks all!
I have encountered a new issue being told that

> File "oswalk.py", line 5, in
>
> encoded = user_file_search.encode('hex')
>   LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs

All the files Im searching through are encoded with HEX, is it because there's an alternative input for hex?

Comment: Remove the empty parentheses!

Comment: `input('Type Millienium2000')`. Closing as typo.

Comment: Are you trying to print that statement before the input? If so you put the string inside the input call: `input('Type Millienium2000')`. You can't add extra parentheses and call it that way

Comment: Ahh thank you so much, its funny how hard it is coming back to coding after a break! , That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put string into parentheses.

Like this:

```
import os
#Imports operating system modules
user_file_search = input('Type Millienium2000')
#Prompt the user to enter password
encoded = user_file_search.encode('hex')
#Decodes files based on hex

for root, dirs, files in os.walk ('/Desktop/POP/PoP_Coursework_Assignment/Svr1/documents$'):
    for data in files :
        pass_file = open(os.path.join(root,data)).read()

if(encoded in pass_file):
    print ('This could be the pass : {}'.format(os.path.join(root,data)))
    print ('Located data: {}'.format(pass_file))
#Prints Data retrived
```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior `input()` returns a string and I do not know why you are trying to call something of it:

`input()('Type Millienium2000')` translates to `"SOMETEXT"('Type Millienium2000')`

If you would like to prompt user for data it should be like this:

`input('Type Millienium2000:')`

Comment: "Conveniently, the person who has hidden this password cannot resist the temptation of leaving their signature. The signature is the text string “Millenium2000”" Basically I need to find the file with the same signature while making the program automated.